# Show JSON array data in function of a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, alert

O want to display data with a alert in function of a variable `(test)`, here is my code but it doesn't't work :

```
var Content = [{
    "01":[{"text":"blablablablabla","apicole":"abeille :o"}],
    "02":[{"text":"blobloblobloblo","apicole":"bzzzz :)"}],
    "03":[{"text":"blibliblibli","apicole":"bzzoooo ;)"}]
}];
var test = apicole ;
alert(Content[0][month][0].test);
```

Comment: You spelled it "test" instead of "text"; also where does "month" come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try accessing the final item with brackets instead of as a prop:

```
var Content = [{
    "01":[{"text":"blablablablabla","apicole":"abeille :o"}],
    "02":[{"text":"blobloblobloblo","apicole":"bzzzz :)"}],
    "03":[{"text":"blibliblibli","apicole":"bzzoooo ;)"}]
}];
month = '01';
var test = 'apicole' ;
alert(Content[0][month][0][test]);​
```

Make sure that month is defined

Answer (score 0):

That is because month is undefined, at least in the snippet you have posted. Also, you are fluctuating between ways of accessing the properties. Try:

```
alert(Content[0]["01"][0]["text"]);
```

Comment: Cant say for sure but perhaps because this shows him how to get the value of the text property and not the property defined by the test variable?